# Changing File-Transfer Plugin from pgb to npm on Phonegap stopped working on Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Since plugins from PhoneGap Build will not be available any more. I've been changing my plugins to use NPM instead.

The below two plugins seem to be working fine on IOS but not on Android.

I have changed this:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="pgb" spec="1.3.3" /> 
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="pgb" spec="0.5.0" />
```

to this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />
```

Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly state the source as coming from `npm`, although that appears to be the default if it's not specified. Here's what I have in my `config.xml`:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="4.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="1.6.0" />
```

If it's still not working, it could be that there have been some API changes since the plugins were last updated on your system. It looks like your `spec` parameters are a bit behind.

Comment: Hi @eb1 are you building for iOS as well? I am having a problem regarding brodysoftsqlite.

Comment: @BizApps: Yes - but the latest sqlite plugin isn't compatible with PG build. You need to use  the extbuild-free plugin instead: `<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free" source="npm" spec="0.8.2" />`.

Comment: Thanks @eb1, i tried is yesterday and its working now. :D